# Converting dynamic to basic disk

Tags: dynamic-disk, disk-management, basic-disk

I converted basic disk to dynamic on my laptop. However, now I cannot install Windows 7 on another partition. I just get message that installing them on dynamic disk is not supported.

Is there a way to convert dynamic disk to basic without losing data on already existing partition?

Comment: I accidentally converted to Dynamic Disk (using Windows's `Disk Management`). But `AOMEI PartitionAssistant Professional` app's `Dynamic Disk Converter` (which can be found in `All Tools` section) was great and without data loss (but needed restart).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are instructions on [non-destructively converting dynamic disks to basic disks](http://mypkb.wordpress.com/2007/03/28/how-to-non-destructively-convert-dynamic-disks-to-basic-disks/).  There are two methods discussed.

**BE VERY CAREFUL.  A MISTAKE CAN RESULT IN THE LOSS OF ALL DATA ON THE DISK.**

1. **If you can boot your system**, follow [Microsoft's instructions](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-hardware/converting-hard-drives-from-dynamic-to-basic/dddcb9c5-20c4-4306-b401-1a7731536f75) after completely backing up *and verifying* anything you don't want to lose from that drive.

([old instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913964) removed by Microsoft see Workaround section; ignore the sections about Live OneCare Firewall) for using the `dskprob.exe` tool from the [Windows Support Tools for WinXP](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=49AE8576-9BB9-4126-9761-BA8011FABF38&displaylang=en).

2. **If you can't boot**, use [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).  The first link in this post contains detailed instructions.  Essentially, if TestDisk can detect your dynamic disk's partitions, it may be able to write out a new, standard partition table -- converting it to a basic disk.

Comment: I can boot it and this information seems promising. I will try it as soon as I get to creating backup.

Comment: excellent plan.  good luck!

Comment: It did not work for me. It all ended with me just clearing everything and restoring from backup.

Comment: @quackquixote I can confirm that it works using testdisk. Proof: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTwPch9acGc

Comment: According to https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=1150673 it loosk like the old instructions of Microsoft just ended up changing the partition type/ID from 42 to 07.

Answer (score -1):

There [seem to be ways](http://www.bing.com/search?q=convert+dynamic+to+basic+disk&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE8SRC).

The official one is to back up the data on the disk, re-partition and -format and then restore the data.

If your volume was used in a stripeset (you had a reason to make it a dynamic volume in the first place, right?), then this should be the only pretty way to keep your data.

Otherwise you seem to be able to get creative with a hex editor. I've done that a few years ago myself but be careful and read up a little on how your disk is organized before destroying anything you might want to keep.