# Unable to create a logical drive, all drives are dynamic

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning

I am unable to create a logical drive from my unallocated space. When I click on *New simple volume* and proceed, it creates another dynamic drive. I tried to creating a logical drive from my Windows 7 disk but the 'new' option (used to create a new drive) is disabled.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

A logical drive is a kind of partition on a basic disk (i.e. a disk with a regular MBR partition table). If the only option for new partitions on a disk is to create dynamic drives, it is probably set up as a dynamic disk. You can't create a logical drive on a dynamic disk.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-are-basic-and-dynamic-disks

Update:

The Disk Management tools included with Windows 7 can convert an empty dynamic disk back to a basic disk.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755238.aspx

Of course, as usual there are ways to do this without having to reformat, but be careful.

See: [Converting dynamic to basic disk](https://superuser.com/questions/65939/converting-dynamic-to-basic-disk)

Comment: I have only 1 disk(disk 0) which contains windows..
so, i can't delete my C drive.

Comment: anybody can tell me what to do??

Comment: Did you look at the last link?

Comment: Yes, I have seen but my pc has only 1 DISK which contains windows and can not be delete all volumes which is required as in 3rd point of last link
i.e. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755238.aspx      Is there any way to create another disk?

Comment: i have created my web page and uploaded a pic of disk management..   my web page: https://sites.google.com/site/amankapagehaiji/

Comment: I have also searched on internet and found this link http://www.dynamic-disk.com/convert-dynamic-disk-to-basic.html   but i am confused in 2nd and 3rd ways given on the site...Can u tell me best and cheapest way?