# How do I convert a dynamic disk to a basic disk without losing data?

Tags: windows, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting dynamic to basic disk](https://superuser.com/questions/65939/converting-dynamic-to-basic-disk)

I have a SATA hard drive and when i am connecting it to a laptop running Windows 7, it's not detecting it. It's showing as a dynamic drive.

I did a web search and found out that I need to convert the *dynamic* disk to *basic*. Isn't there any way to read this disk without converting? If not, how do I convert it without losing data?

I don't have any extra backup drive. I tried a few applications, but all of them were demo versions.

Comment: No matter if you find a supposedly "safe" method of doing this, you still need to BACK UP YOUR DATA! I can't stress this enough.  With anything like this where there is a possibility of anything going wrong, data backup is the way to go, or you might be sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Back up your data before doing anything.

Hard core Geek method, you change the value of sector 0 location 1C2 from 42(dynamic) to 07 (basic), using a disk editor
http://www.wilderssecurity.com/showthread.php?t=191006

[image]
.

.

Alternate Software method
http://www.partition-tool.com/resource/convert-dynamic-disk-to-basic.htm