# After having 3 partitions, the disk converted to a dynamic disk and I cannot change it back (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, dynamic-disk, basic-disk

I started off with one disk, and it was a basic disk. I partitioned it to install Windows 8.1, then ran out of space, so I made another partition, and extended my Windows 8 partition into that. But then, Windows 8 stopped booting, and that was because my disk had now become a dynamic disk.

I want to convert it back to a basic disk, but still keep all my data. (I've uninstalled Windows 8)

It would be preferable to not install any 3rd-party software or freemium stuff.

Comment: What makes you think your booting problems are because the partition is a dynamic disk?

Comment: UEFI probably cannot boot from Dynamic Disks. But in that case Windows probably would’ve refused to convert it in the first place. Changing back is only possible when all partitions are removed.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried to reinstall Windows 8 onto it, and it gave me an error saying that it could not install because one or more disks were dynamic (I don't remember exactly)

Comment: I've been struggling with boot issues for months. I can readily create a bootable flash drive, put a BCD on it, tweak it and do what ever I want. Trying to do the same on a dynamic disk though returns errors and/or fails to boot every time so I'm suspecting that EFI boot from a dynamic disk isn't possible, but I can't find any clear answer and Windows was happy to convert my basic disk to dynamic like the OP describes.

Answer (score 1):

Several times I managed to convert a dynamic disk back to basic by using [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). Just run it, choose Intel partition table, let it scan the disk and detect existing partitions. Then write the partition table. This will recreate a standard partition table and the disk will be detected as basic. You can try to run testdisk under WinPE or you can boot Knoppix - testdisk is available in the standard image.

You can find more details in answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/65939/converting-dynamic-to-basic-disk?rq=1).

Comment: I have used testdisk to convert a dynamic disk back to basic once and it worked