# Can't boot from an OEM recovery partition, error mentions dynamic disk

Tags: boot, laptop, sony-vaio, hard-drive-recovery, oem

I have a Sony Vaio laptop VGN FS515 H.

I try to start the Recovery partition Tools by typing <kbd>F10</kbd> during POST.
The problem is that the recovery partition (OEM) won't boot and an error message says
`Reinstallation is impossible because Hard Drive was converted to dynamic.`

[image: Screenshot of disk manager]

How can I solve that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you already posted the answer. Just with the wrong focus:

[image]

To make sure: please add the precise error message to your post. You can do this using the [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/828372/edit) function.

As to the actual problem: Please read this post [Converting dynamic to basic disk](https://superuser.com/questions/65939/converting-dynamic-to-basic-disk). Note that this is something which I did not test myself and my own preferred way of recovering would be to wipe the disk (with diskpart clean - loosing all data) and to recover from backups (ghost images, wim files, clean re-install... pick your flavour).

Alternative solutions: (Partially from the post linked above):

1. Manually edit the partition table changing partition types from 42 to 07. ([Useful tool for this](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/). This is described in details [on this website](http://strangelyperfect.tv/6415/how-to-convert-a-dynamic-disk-to-basic-disk-in-windows-7/#sthash.ZHhE2tUY.dpbs).
2. Or do the same using `diskprop.exe.` as described on http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/913964
3. Wipe the disk clean (diskpart, select disk 0, clean, create partition primary. Reinstall. Recover data from backup).
4. Try [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)
5. Try a partition manager [like this one](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm)

But whatever you do. First make a full disk backup.

Comment: Hi Hennes Thanks for paying attention to my question . The error is exactly : Reinstalltion is impossible because Hard Drive was converted to dynamic

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to set it back with live-CD - exsistent system will be unbootable. You can try to set boot flag on this partition.. I reinstalled Windows 8 with broken boot on toshiba in this way.