# dual boot linux installation type empty

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot

I have win7 in my PC and I want to install Ubuntu alongside.

I shrink-ed ~40 GB from the C drive to install the Ubuntu on it.

I prepared a USB drive with the OS. I found that the screen `installation type` is empty and I can't find any of the PC drives.

My issue is the same of this: [Installation type empty on 16.04 for a dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802152/installation-type-empty-on-16-04-for-a-dual-boot). The proposed solution is to change `SATA setting to AHCI` in the bios settings. I entered the bios settings of my PC (`HP EliteBook 8560w`) and I found that it's already AHCI (`SATA device mode`).

I think the problem is due to the partition type of drives, but I don't know how to change them (I don't want to lose my installed win7).

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: First, use the latest LTS version, 18.04, unless it's a 32-bit PC. Second, be sure the Linux partition is left *unformatted*. Finally, test the installation media on another PC, just to see if it shows partitions... it could be a fault in creating media.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik , 1)Yes I'm using this version (64-bit). 2) Yes, I just shrinked it without doing format. 3) I tried the installation USB on my surface pro and it works!, the partitions are there! Do you suggest something else?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/65939/converting-dynamic-to-basic-disk then  in Windows, use Disk Management (right-click on Windows START icon at far lower left then choose from list) to see if that drive is formatted as a Basic Disk or a Dynamic Disk. Ubuntu can't access Dynamic Disks.

Comment: @K7AAY , Then I have to format my disk!

Comment: Have you confirmed the disk is Dynamic? Could be another issue. One step at a time, please, for there are ways to do that without a wipe-and-reload.

Comment: I downloaded a software called `partition manager` which works like disk manager. I tried to check whether the disk is dyn or basic. When I did right click to choose `convert to ******` it appear to me `convert to dynamic` which means that the disc is basic